# Apache Hue or Apache Ambari - how to install and configure them manually

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hue

I am seting up 5 node hadoop 2.5.1 cluster with zookeeper, oozie, hive and hbase. I currently have hadoop 2 and zookeeper installed and running. I want to setup some kind of UI management for all the services so I can monitor health and do admin tasks from it. I see all documents for Ambari and Hue are geared towards Hortornworks and Cloudera respectively. Is there any step-by-step guide for either of these UI console that tells me how to configure them for my existing hadoop services ?

Answer (score 4):

Hue has this [blog post](http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/) about how to integrate with any cluster.

We also recommend this [doc](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh_hue_configure.html). It says Cloudera but this is the same instruction for any Hadoop (as Hue uses only standard APIs).

Answer (score 1):

Officialy, Ambari does not support installation on an existing cluster. When you install it you have to remove previous hadoop components. As mentioned on [Ambari FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/API+usage+scenarios%2C+troubleshooting%2C+and+other+FAQs) 
Installing a new cluster on top of an existing cluster

> When installing a Hadoop cluster via Ambari on hosts that already have Hadoop bits installed (including an existing cluster deployed via Ambari), perform the following:

```
Stop all the services on all the nodes(including ganglia and nagios)
It is also a good practice to delete the rpms from all nodes.

search for the rpms:
rpm -qa | grep ganglia
rpm -qa | grep oozie
rpm -qa | grep sqoop
rpm -qa | grep pig
rpm -qa | grep nagios
rpm -qa | grep hadoop

and remove them :
rpm -e <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks documentation provides Hue install instructions as well :

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/bk_installing_manually_book-20150721.pdf

Chapter 14. Installing Hue

Hue requires services to be stopped on cluster, no need to remove them like Ambari install requires.